# Trying to trigger event when a CellEditor in a Grid cell is changed

Tags: python-3.x, wxpython, wxformbuilder

I have a table that displays Job details in a window created with wxFormBuilder.  The table has a financials column labelled Finance that contains a comboBox (SetCellEditor) in each row (record).

The comboBox holds the values from the array

```
finance_options = ['Not Started', 'Preparing Day Sheets', 'Day Sheets Sent', 'PO Received', 'Partially Invoiced', 'Fully Invoiced']
```

When I change this dropdown I want to call a method called onFinanceChanged.

I would normally use the option in wxFormBuilder to assign the method to a cellChanged event, but that triggers if any cell in the table is changed.

```
    def populate_job_grid(self, jobs):
        finance_options = ['Not Started', 'Preparing Day Sheets', 'Day Sheets Sent', 'PO Received',
                           'Partially Invoiced', 'Fully Invoiced']
        for i in range(0, len(jobs)):
            self.jobNumberGrid.InsertRows(0)
        row = 0
        for job in jobs:
            year = arrow.get(job.created_at).date()
            job_year = str(year.year)[2:]
            self.jobNumberGrid.SetCellValue(row, 0, str(job.job_no))
            self.jobNumberGrid.SetCellValue(row, 1, job_year)
            self.jobNumberGrid.SetCellValue(row, 2, str(job.site))
            self.jobNumberGrid.SetCellValue(row, 3, str(job.client.name))
            self.jobNumberGrid.SetCellValue(row, 4, str(job.job_description))
            self.jobNumberGrid.SetCellValue(row, 5, str(job.user.name))
            created = arrow.get(job.created_at).date()
            created_at = datetime.datetime.strptime(str(created), "%Y-%m-%d").strftime("%d-%m-%Y")
            self.jobNumberGrid.SetCellValue(row, 6, created_at)
            self.jobNumberGrid.SetCellValue(row, 7, job.finance)
            finance = wx.grid.GridCellChoiceEditor(finance_options, allowOthers=True)
            self.jobNumberGrid.SetCellEditor(row, 7, finance).Bind(self.jobNumberGrid.EVT_GRID_CELL_CHANGED,
                                                                   self.onFinanceChange)

            row = row + 1
```

As you can see I tried to bind EVT_GRID_CELL_CHANGED to the cell but this gives "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'Bind'" error.

Any ideas?

Thanks Paul.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SetCellEditor` has no return value, so there is nothing there to use to call `Bind`. Instead you should use `self.jobNumberGrid` to bind the event handler. It will be called for any cell value change, but you can get the row,col of the changed cell and then either ignore it, or call `self.onFinanceChange` based on which column the event is coming from.